# Odd Streak of Heads

Tags: probability, expected-value

On average, how many times do you need to flip a fair coin before you have seen a run of an odd number of heads, followed by a tail?

The answer in the book is 6 which is obtained through solving the equation below which I understand

x = 1/2*(x+1) + 1/4*(2+x) + 1/4*1

What I don't understand why I get a different answer in book when I calculate the expected value of counts.

S = 2*(1/2)^2 + 4*(1/2)^4 + 6*(1/2)^6 + 8*(1/2)^8 + ....

S = 8/9.

why it is not equal to 6???

Comment: Please explain how you approached the problem, where does the computation come from? And how did you interpret the solution given in the book? Also, use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

It's much less than $\ 6\ $ because your series $\ S\ $ doesn't give you the correct expected number for the count.  It's evident from your expression for $\ S\ $ that it assumes there are *no* sequences of $\ 3, 5$ or $\ 7\ $ tosses and only *one* sequence of each of $\ 4, 6$ or $\ 8\ $ tosses where your first odd sequence of heads followed by a tail terminates.  But that's not correct.  The sequence $\ THT\ $ of $\ 3\ $ tosses, for instance, is obviously one where you've just seen your first run of an odd number of heads followed by a tail.  In fact, it's possible to show that the number of sequences of $\ n\ $ tosses where you've first seen your run of odd heads followed by a tail is the $\ (n-1)^\text{nth}\ $ [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence) $\ F_{n-1}\ $ (with $\ F_0=0, F_1=1\ $ etc.).  A correct series for the expected count is therefore
$$
S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{nF_{n-1}}{2^n}\ ,
$$
and this does in fact sum to $\ 6\ $.